# ALTER TABLE Staff ADD FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES Hotel(hotelNo) Error Code: 1072. Key column 'hotelNo' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

```
create table Hotel(
hotelNo integer, 
name varchar(20), 
address varchar(20),
StaffNo integer,     
PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo));

ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD  FOREIGN KEY (staffNo) REFERENCES Staff(staffNo);
```

** this one goes fine**

```
create table Staff(
staffNo integer primary key,
fName varchar(20),
lName varchar(20), 
gender varchar (10), 
dob date, 
salary decimal,
telNo decimal);

ALTER TABLE Staff ADD  FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES Hotel(hotelNo);
```

**after the above line an error occurred I did the exact alter to alter another table room it goes right**
the error is:

> 0 243 17:33:14    ALTER TABLE Staff ADD  FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES
> Hotel(hotelNo)    Error Code: 1072. Key column 'hotelNo' doesn't exist in
> table 0.015 sec

Comment: True, there is no hotelno in staff Also why would you want to tie staff to a specific hotel??

Comment: Still, if staff can be connected to to many hotel and vice versa you should da a bridge table, a ring foreign key as you attempt will not work, because the refrenced number must exist prior to the insert of the child row, but as both a rererlated, no row can be inserted or you assigne NULL

Comment: `foreign key` is a constraint. 1st you need to have a column to add a constraint on it.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself explain himself!

Just read is properly, `Key column 'hotelNo' doesn't exist in table`, its clearly mean you don't have a column 'hotelNo', you have to add column 'hotelNo' in table 'Staff' with the same type and length of the primary key of 'Hotel' i.e hotelNo.

```
ALTER TABLE `Staff` ADD `hotelNo` INT NOT NULL, ADD INDEX (`hotelNo`);
```